# How to install netbeans v8.1 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: apt, software-installation, netbeans

Nobody seems to talk about version 8.1, can anyone please guide me through?

Comment: That title though @andrew.46...it explains why google failed to find it for me. Looking that into!

Comment: Poor title for the question but the answer (which is mine) makes up for it :)

Comment: @andrew.46 absolutely shameless :p

Comment: That's ok guys, I mean if it was something relevant with my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716255/why-does-this-program-print-forked-4-times/26716300#26716300), I would also prompt the OP to it. However, the other OP doesn't even accept the answer. I think that a merging would be nice. @andrew.46, I am still installing.